# How to Replace Description Text for All Users in an Organizational Unit using Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, powershell-ise

I have added about 1700+ users to Active Directory using a CSV file. I accidentially tried to use `\n` to seperate some attributes between them. But it did not escape new line. Instead typed it as is.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\UsersList.csv"            

foreach ($User in $Users)            
{
    $Name = $User.Name
    $AccountPassword = $User.AccountPassword
    $City = $User.City
    $Company = $User.Company
    $GivenName = $User.GivenName
    $SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName      
    $Surname = $User.Surname
    $UserPrincipalName = $User.UPN
    $Displayname = $User.Name   
    $Description = "Desc1: " + $User.Desc1 + "\nDesc2: " + $User.Desc2 + "\nDesc3: " + $User.Desc3 + "\nDesc4: " + $User.Desc4
    $Path = $User.Path


    New-ADUser -Name "$Name" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -SamAccountName "$SamAccountName" -UserPrincipalName "$UserPrincipalName" -GivenName "$GivenName" -Surname "$Surname" -Description "$Description" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $AccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$Path" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
```

Now I want to change those "\n" in Descriptions for all users.

I can get users using

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {description -like "\n"}
```

I need a command that using `.Replace("\n"," - ")`. I do not know how to use it to reach my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a Foreach-Object loop to find all the Descriptions with your filter and pipe that to Set-Aduser.

```
         $Description = "-Desc1: " + $User.Desc1 + "-Desc2: " + $User.Desc2 + "-Desc3: " + $User.Desc3 + "-Desc4: " + $User.Desc4

        foreach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Filter {description -like "*\n*"}) )
        {
            $User.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -Description $Description
        }
```

#### To update the users from the CSV

```
            foreach ($User in $users )
            {
                $User.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -Description $user.Description
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Set-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {description -like "*\n*"} -Properties Description |
  ForEach-Object {
    $newDescription = $_.Description.Replace('\n', ' - ')
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Description $newDescription
  }
```

Note that with the `-like` operator you need to add wildcards before and after the `\n`, otherwise you'd only get users where the description consists of just `\n` and nothing else. You also need to tell `Get-ADUser` to include the property `Description` as it isn't among the properties returned by default.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers. It did not work. It gives no error but did not replace

Comment: I have changed all the user descrptions to  `$_.Description.Replace("\n"," - ")`. Now I have to refer to csv file again. My problem evolved to "how to update users' description from csv file?"

Comment: @zkanoca Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Comment: Since I cannot change the modification back to original state, I said that. But I have found my own solution. Thanks