# Unexpected Token 'Set-ADUser' in expression when trying to change particular Descriptions in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, unexpected-token

This is a two-fold question.

First, I'm trying to get this PS command to work (trying to pull accounts with certain characters in their description and replace those characters), and it keeps giving me the "Unexpected token 'Set-ADUser' in expression or statement." error:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {description -like "*Example*"} -Properties description | ForEach-Object {$newDescription = $_.Description.Replace("Example", "Example2") Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Description $newDescription}
```

I'm basing this off of what I found here (Second Answer - by Ansgar Wiechers) [How to Replace Description Text for All Users in an Organizational Unit using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179855/how-to-replace-description-text-for-all-users-in-an-organizational-unit-using-po)

Any Help is much appreciated! Never used a site like this before but don't want to spend Way too much time on this.

My second question relates to the first one, with examples on the link mentioned previously. Is there a way to move to the next line in PS without hitting Enter?
The reason I ask is when I copied the code from the above link into Word, edited it, then copied into PS and ran it, it ran fine--didn't actually change anything, but it ran. When I try to run it all as one line, it throws the error.

Are people building the commands in another program when they do it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. The only mistake was that you needed to use `$_.DistinguishedName` or `$_.SamAccountName` for the `-Identity` parameter of `Set-ADUser`.

These things happen quite often when you try and put everything on one single line like you did. This makes reading the code very hard to do.

I also have changed the `.Replace` into `-replace`. This makes it case-insensitive (same as your `-Filter`),so now also 'example' will be replaced by 'Example2'.

Here's the new code.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Description -like "*Example*"} -Properties Description | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newDescription = $_.Description -replace "Example", "Example2"
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Description $newDescription
    }
```

Comment: Theo, Thanks a ton for the input! I was able to get it to work, but only by putting the text in Notepad++ and formatting it similar to how you did before copying and pasting into PS.
Any idea why this might be or if there's a way to write it out like this directly in PS (my second question)??

Comment: Well, you could (should?) use the PowerShell ISE. There you have a full PS editor where you can copy/paste in the code straight away. Anyway, if you feel my answer has helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the outlined checkmark image.

Comment: p.s. For easy access to the ISE, just create a desktop shortcut and point it to `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe`

Comment: Thanks again, Theo. Didn't think to use PS ISE as I've never really used it before. Answer accepted.